# Parse migration tool to migrate directly to dynamodb

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform, dbaas

We have to migrate from parse server but use parse API to own hosted server. We have two options

Mongo db

Amazon Dynamodb
The parse migration tool can be used to migrate to mongo db but we want to move to Amazon Dynamo db after reading comparison on both.
If we use any db link in parse migration tools it check if link starts with mongodb
So I doubt would it be possible to use parse migration tool directly to migrate to dynamodb.
If above is possible then can we start with localhost dynamo db
Any help will be highly appreciated.